# What should be the test value when finding important factors?

Tags: t-test, spss

When doing One-sample t-test on a variable which ask respondents to rate a purchasing factor of a product like price on a scale of 1 to 5 with 1=least important and 5=very important, what should be the test value if I want to find out if the variable is important or not important in purchase decision?

Should it be 2.5 or should it be 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally up to you.  If you want to test for it to be significantly different than 2.5 (neutral), then chose, 2.5.  If you want to test if it's significantly different than 4 (somewhat important), then chose 4.

Comment: Okay got it what if I want to find out which factors are insignificant?

Comment: @newguy, Please accept this question if it helped and then ask a separate question.